# Selecting Q, R and P for Kalman filter in 2D object tracking

Tags: kalman-filter

I have time-series with locations of a tracked object in (x,y) format, where (x,y) are are calculated in meters from some chosen origin and are corrupted by the noise. Object is assumed to be stationary most of the time and slowly moving on short distances form time to time. I want to reduce this noise with the help of the Kalman filter.

So, I understand that Q is the covariance of the process noise and R is the covariance of the observation noise. But what should be my approach if from the available data I do not really have a clue how big the variances of the process and observation noise might be?

Should I start just with identity matrices for Q, R and P? And how to select how I should change them in case the results are not satisfactory?

I do no have any problem with math/implementation details of Kalman filter as it is extensively described online. But usually I see that some matrices are assumed as suitable for the given task, and it is not clear to me how I actually should select them.

Maybe somebody who has experience with a similar task can give me some directions?